# perl to convert from H:MM:SS to MM.MMMM

Tags: perl

I need to use perl to read in from a text file DOW YYYY-MM-DD H:MM:SS.S, and then output decimal minutes MM.MMMM. Given the input text file

```
Fri 2013-06-14 0:59:15.3
Sat 2013-06-15 1:01:30.6
Sun 2013-06-16 1:03:45.9
```

I want to compute the decimal minutes values

```
(60*0)+59+(15.3/60) = 59.2550
(60*1)+01+(30.6/60) = 61.5100
(60*1)+03+(45.6/60) = 63.7600
```

and then output

```
(59.2550, 61.5100, 63.7600)
```

Comment: Not all minutes have 60 seconds, so your answer could be off by a second with your approach.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming every line on the text file is a date on it's own, and the file you're reading from is on the same directory and called `input.txt`, I'd do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @result = ();

{
  open (my $file, "<", "input.txt") or die "cannot open < input.txt: $!";
  while(<$file>){
    my @current = split(/:/,substr($_,15));
    push(@result, (60*$current[0]) + $current[1] + ($current[2]/60));
  }
}

print "(" . join(',',@result) . ")";
```

Comment: You should use lexical filehandles and three-argument open.

Comment: @simbabque Good point, I just improved my answer based on your good suggestions and made the code better...

Comment: You should also `use strict` and `use warnings`; check the success of your `open`, and `die` if it fails with a string that includes `$!`; and use a regex `/:/` for the first parameter of `split`.

Comment: @Borodin changed, thanks. I understand the reason for the other things, but why is it better to use a regex `/:/` for `split` ?

Comment: @darkajax: Because it is used as a regex however you quote it, and it is best to be clear.

Comment: the exception to the split regex argument is `' '` (a single space in quotes) which is a special case and splits on whitespace. (Even more reason to be explicit about using an obvious regex with split)

Comment: It's good to know, thanks everybody :)

Comment: I do not get any output when I run the script $ ./convert_to_min_04.pl

Comment: You need to send the data via STDIN to the script, so $ convert_to_min_04.pl < elapsed_01.txt, and you'd need to call perl first unless you've added the shebang lin

Comment: @plusplus: No. The program explicitly opens and reads from `input.txt`.

Comment: @GregCoats: This program reads from `input.txt`. If your file has a different name then you must change the program so the the `open` call accesses `elapsed_01.txt` instead.

Comment: @GregCoats it's as Borodin said, just change "input.txt" for your file name...

Answer (score 3):

The format of your input file isn't very clear, but this seems to produce what you want. It expects the path to the input file as a command-line parameter.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @minutes;
while (<>) {
  push @minutes, $1*60 + $2 + $3/60 if /(\d+):(\d+):([\d.]+)/;
}

printf "(%s)\n", join ', ', map sprintf('%.4f', $_), @minutes;
```

**output**

```
(59.2550, 61.5100, 63.7650)
```

Comment: `$1 * 24` should be `$1 * 60` instead because hour -> minute

Comment: @doubleDown: You're right ofc. Thank you.

Comment: $ cat ./elapsed_01.txt 
Fri 2013-06-14 0:59:15.3 
Sat 2013-06-15 1:01:30.6 
Sun 2013-06-16 1:03:45.9
$ ./convert_to_min_03.pl ./elapsed_01.txt

Comment: $ cat ./elapsed_01.txt 
Fri 2013-06-14 0:59:15.3 
Sat 2013-06-15 1:01:30.6 
Sun 2013-06-16 1:03:45.9
Gregs-Mac-mini:scripts gregcoats$ ./convert_to_min_03.pl ./elapsed_01.txt

Comment: I do not get any output $ cat ./elapsed_01.txt 
Fri 2013-06-14 0:59:15.3 
Sat 2013-06-15 1:01:30.6 
Sun 2013-06-16 1:03:45.9
Gregs-Mac-mini:scripts gregcoats$ ./convert_to_min_03.pl ./elapsed_01.txt

Comment: You need to send the data via STDIN to the script, so `$  convert_to_min_03.pl < elapsed_01.txt`, and you'd need to call `perl` first unless you've added the shebang line

Comment: @GregCoats: As I said in my solution, the program expects the path to the input file as a command-line parameter. Just put the filename as a parameter on the command line. `convert_to_min_03.pl elapsed_01.txt`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to capture your input:

```
my $time = "Fri 2013-06-14 0:59:15.3";
$time =~ /(\d+?):(\d+?):(.+)$/  #The time captured in three components
my $hours   = $1;
my $minute  = $2;
my $seconds = $3;
```

The [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) describes what you want to match on your line. The `$` means anchoring my expression on the end of the line. The `(..)` are capture groups. These capture what is matched in my regular expression and makes them available via the `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` variables.

If you never learned about regular expressions, you should. Regular expressions are very powerful, and you should read up on them in the link above, or try the [Perldoc tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Now, that I have the various pieces of my time captured (and assuming 60 second minutes and 60 minute hours), I can now do my calculation:

```
my $time_in_seconds = ( $hours * 3600 ) + ( $minutes * 60 ) + $seconds;
my $time_in_minutes = $time_in_seconds / 60;
```

Division on computers has accuracy problems since it's hard to represent a fractional decimal number in base 2. Therefore, I prefer to multiply it all out, and then divide it by 60.

Once you have the time, you need to print it out in the format you want. That calls for [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

```
printf "%9.4f\n", $time_in_minutes;
```

The `%9.4f` specifies the format. The `f` says this is a *floating point* number (basically, a non-integer). The `4` represents the number of decimals. The `9` represents the field width which includes the decimal, the four on the other side of the decimal, and the minus sign. Thus, this will allow a width of up to `-9999.999` which is more than enough.

Putting it all together....

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

while ( my $time = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $time;
    $time =~ /(\d+?):(\d+?):(.+)$/;  #The time captured in three components
    my $hours    = $1;
    my $minutes  = $2;
    my $seconds  = $3;
    my $time_in_seconds = ( $hours * 3600 ) + ( $minutes * 60 ) + $seconds;
    my $time_in_minutes = $time_in_seconds / 60;
    printf qq(%9.4f\n), $time_in_minutes;
}

__DATA__
Fri 2013-06-14 0:59:15.3
Sat 2013-06-15 1:01:30.6
Sun 2013-06-16 1:03:45.9
```

Now run it:

```
$ ./test.pl 
  59.2550
  61.5100
  63.7650
```

Looks about right.